# Jenkins Scan Multibranch Pipeline fails Host key verification failed

Tags: jenkins, ssh

Jenkins is failing with an SSH issue when it tries to scan the multibranch pipeline and ssh is giving "Host key verification failed":

```
[Wed Sep 21 01:10:09 PDT 2022] Starting branch indexing...
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.31.1'
using GIT_SSH to set credentials jenkins@jenkinsserver SSH private key
[INFO] Currently running in a labeled security context
[INFO] Currently SELinux is 'enforcing' on the host
 > /usr/bin/chcon --type=ssh_home_t /tmp/jenkins-gitclient-ssh7000755047282481393.key
Verifying host key using manually-configured host key entries
 > git ls-remote --symref -- ssh://jenkins@jenkinsserver.corp.contoso.com/vol/git/cmb.git # timeout=10
ERROR: [Wed Sep 21 01:10:09 PDT 2022] Could not update folder level actions from source blueocean
[Wed Sep 21 01:10:09 PDT 2022] Finished branch indexing. Indexing took 0.13 sec
FATAL: Failed to recompute children of CertAccord
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git ls-remote --symref -- ssh://jenkins@jenkinsserver.corp.contoso.com/\
vol/git/cmb.git" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: No ECDSA host key is known for jenkinsserver.corp.contoso.com and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2697)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2111)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2009)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2000)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.getRemoteSymbolicReferences(CliGitAPIImpl.java:3675)
        at jenkins.plugins.git.AbstractGitSCMSource.retrieveActions(AbstractGitSCMSource.java:1152)
        at jenkins.scm.api.SCMSource.fetchActions(SCMSource.java:848)
        at jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject.computeChildren(MultiBranchProject.java:598)
        at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.ComputedFolder.updateChildren(ComputedFolder.java:278)
        at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.FolderComputation.run(FolderComputation.java:166)
        at jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject$BranchIndexing.run(MultiBranchProject.java:1032)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:107)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:449)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I'm aware that this problem indicates the ssh client is receiving an ssh server signature that it doesn't recognize (e.g. it's not in known_hosts).

If I "su - jenkins" on the jenkinsserver I can manually run git and ssh without a problem:

```
$ git ls-remote --symref -- ssh://jenkins@jenkinsserver.corp.contoso.com/vol/git/cmb.git
ref: refs/heads/master  HEAD
f79a54e2233749e0f0a9cf01        HEAD
... snip ...
$ ssh jenkinsserver.corp.contoso.com date
Wed Sep 21 01:45:20 PDT 2022
$ grep jenkinsserver ~/.ssh/known_hosts
jenkinsserver.corp.contoso.com ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHN....
```

This means that there is some other known_hosts file that Jenkins is somehow telling ssh to use. I just can't figure out where that file is!

Since this is a branch scan it's running on the jenkin's server, right?

The jenkinsserver is a RHEL 8.6 system. Jenkins version 2.361.1-1.1

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution for this. In Manage Jenkins > Configure Global Security > Git Host Key Verification Configuration I changed it to "Accept first connection". It was set to "Manually provide keys".